# The right XPATH for IMPORTXML (for Yahoo Finance)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula, yahoo-finance

I am trying to extract the Stock Price History Section from Yahoo Finance Statistics page. The following Xpath seems to point to the right section, but the function doesn't work in GoogleSheets. Can someone let me know how to correct this?

```
=IMPORTXML(
"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/PLUG/key-statistics?p=PLUG",
"//*[@id="Col1-0-KeyStatistics-Proxy"]/section/div[3]")
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The content as shown by Inspect Element is likely dynamic and can't be relied upon. Try to find an API instead of scraping.

Answer (score -1):

The `div` that you are looking for is one level deeper.

To get that one you have to use:

```
//*[@id="Col1-0-KeyStatistics-Proxy"]/section/div[2]/div[3]
```

if the order would change you could also use:

```
//div[h2[span[.='Financial Highlights']]]
```